# Creating an SSH Key Pair for User Authentication with Expect in Bash

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I have tried the following steps to set ssh passwordless (SSH Key Pair Authentication)login.

Set ip and port in bash.

```
ip="xxxx"
port="xxxx"
```

Set ssh config file on client side

```
cat > $HOME/.ssh/config <<EOF 
Host $ip
IdentityFile $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
User root
EOF
```

Create a ssh key pair  on client side

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -q -b 2048 -N ""
```

Push id_rsa into ssh server from client side.
Prepare for ssh server

```
ssh -p $port  root@$ip  "mkdir -p  /root/.ssh"
```

Push authorized file into ssh server

```
scp -P $port id_rsa.pub root@$ip:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Set permission for authorized file

```
ssh -p $port root@$ip "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Succeeded!

Now i want to write all steps into a one-click bash script for the job.
Here is my try.

```
#! /bin/bash
ip="xxxx"
port="xxxx"
pass="yyyy"

cat > $HOME/.ssh/config <<EOF 
Host $ip
IdentityFile $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.bwg_root
User root
EOF

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.bwg_root -q -b 2048 -N ""
cd  $HOME/.ssh

    /usr/bin/expect <<EOF
    spawn ssh -p $port  root@$ip  "mkdir -p  /root/.ssh"
    expect "password:"
    send "$pass\r"
    spawn scp -P $port id_rsa.pub root@$ip:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    expect "password:"
    send "$pass\r"
    spawn ssh -p $port root@$ip "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
    expect "password:"
    send "$pass\r"
EOF
```

It got the following output info:

```
spawn ssh -p xxxx root@yyyy mkdir -p  /root/.ssh
root@yyyy's password: spawn scp -P xxxx id_rsa.bwg.pub root@yyyy:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
root@yyyy's password: spawn ssh -p xxxx root@yyyy chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd simplify it with `sshpass`.

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="x.x.x.x"
port="xx"
export SSHPASS="yyy"

cat >$HOME/.ssh/config <<EOF
Host $ip
IdentityFile $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.bwg_root
User root
EOF

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.bwg_root" -q -b 2048 -N ""
cd "$HOME/.ssh" || exit 1

sshpass -e ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -p "$port" "root@$ip" "mkdir -p -m 700 /root/.ssh"
sshpass -e scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -P "$port" id_rsa.bwg_root.pub "root@$ip:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
sshpass -e ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -p "$port" "root@$ip" "chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Btw: I replaced last `id_rsa.pub` with `id_rsa.bwg_root.pub` and added `-m 700` to `mkdir` and removed `chmod 700 .ssh`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ssh-copy-id` to push the new key to the remote host. You'll need to enter the password for *that* login, of course, but it's the last time you'll have to use it.

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="x.x.x.x"
port="xx"
id_file=$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_$ip

cat > $HOME/.ssh/config <<EOF
HOST $ip
IdentityFile $id_file
User root
EOF

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_$ip" -q -b 2048 -N ""

ssh-copy-id -i "$id_file" -p "$port" root@"$ip"
```

As a general rule, *always* look for a non- (or less) interactive solution using existing tools before trying `except`.